# Sharethis doesn't load with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharethis

I am using jquery infinity scroll and jquery masonry plugin on one my projects and also I an using a Sharethis buttons on the pages.

problem is that the Sharethis button dosen't load on the 2nd page, which is loaded using ajax. I am using normal Sharethis code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "ur-de6b7a4a-e967-4778-5476-54ab547cb1bb", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>


<span class='st_facebook_hcount' st_url="http://<?php echo $settings['siteurl'];?>/listing-<?php echo $row['id'];?>-<?php echo $PageLink;?>.html" st_title="<?php echo $LongTitle;?>" displayText='Facebook'></span>
<span class='st_twitter_hcount' st_url="http://<?php echo $settings['siteurl'];?>/listing-<?php echo $row['id'];?>-<?php echo $PageLink;?>.html" st_title="<?php echo $LongTitle;?>" displayText='Tweet'></span>
<span class='st_pinterest_hcount' st_url="http://<?php echo $settings['siteurl'];?>/listing-<?php echo $row['id'];?>-<?php echo $PageLink;?>.html" st_title="<?php echo $LongTitle;?>" displayText='Pinterest'></span>
```

Can anyone tell me a fix for this? did search everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Since it apparently is not good enough of an answer, look here for how you can create the sharethis buttons with javascript: http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/475079-share-properties-and-sharing-custom-information#Dynamic_Specification_through_JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that you can use `stButtons.locateElements();` fix this this problem. thank everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with sharethis and Ajax pagination. The buttons was not showing after posts loaded by Ajax so I've searched and found this. I've just added the function stButtons.locateElements(); on Ajax success:

something like `success: stButtons.locateElements();`

Hope this will be helpful for someone like me.

Thanks

Ibnul

Answer (score 0):

Call this function on Ajax success

stButtons.locateElements();

i.e:

```
success: function (response) {
  .............
  Your Code
  .............
  stButtons.locateElements();
}
```